# Why does a 5GHz Wi-Fi signal experience less interference than its 2.4GHz counterpart?

Tags: frequency, interference, wavelength, electrical-engineering, microwaves

I am thinking in this in terms of their respective wavelengths.  The signal operating at a 2.4GHz frequency would have a significantly longer wavelength than the the other signal at a 5GHz frequency.  Wouldn't this mean that, as a percentage of its wavelength, the 2.4GHz signal would be less likely to experience either constructive or destructive interference (i.e. be very close to 180° out of phase)?

I would think that the interference as a function of radial distance from the source would increase much more drastically with the 5GHz signal.  Although, the 5GHz signal is usually touted as having less interference from other wireless devices operating on this frequency band with the source.  Why is this?

Comment: There's a lot more stuff broadcasting around $2.4~\rm GHz$. Phones, bluetooth, car alarms, garage door openers, microwaves, etc.

Comment: So, it's rather just that there are more devices using the 2.4GHz?  Hypothetically speaking, if every device would be switched to a 5GHz instead of a 2.4GHz, would it be like I mentioned above, with more interference?

Comment: My WiFi access point samples the frequency range and produces a report of what’s active... The 2.4 band has crowded with devices, but the 5GHz band is basically empty... there are still way fewer people on 5GHz.

Answer (score 1):

There are severall factors contributing to greater interference at 2,4Ghz frequncies:

1. 2,4Ghz penetrates throught walls and obstacles better than 5Ghz, yielding greater range for interference signals.
2. Wireless mice, bluetooth, wireless baby monitors, microwave ovens and whole bunch of outher non-wifi devises do use 2,4Ghz frequncies and not 5Ghz.
3. 5Ghz band is wider than 2,4Ghz band (you have more frequencies to stay clear from interference).
4. There are overlapping 20Mhz Wifi channels only on 2,4Ghz band. I personally got my speedtest result to increase from 1,5Mbps to 40Mbps just from changing from channel 1 to channel 4 (neighbors wifi were located at channel 4 for whole duration, device only supports 1ss at 20Mhz - 72Mbps theoretical). Wifi networks on the same channel do play nicely with one anouther while they are pure interference to one anouther if on overlapping channels.

P. S. I would ban 802.11b (only allowing 802.11g, 802.11n, and 802.11ax or later for 2,4 Ghz wifi) and wifi channels 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12 (allow only channels 1, 5, 9, 13 and channel width of 20Mhz/40Mhz, not 22Mhz of 802.11b as that will interfere with channel 20Mhz apart)

Answer (score -3):

From what I understand about 5Ghz is it travels in more of a direct angle/direction. This is why if we switch to 5G there would have to be more cell towers/base stations. There's less of a chance of to waves coming together in faze. I Think? -Austin Hungerford

Comment: No, I think none of this is correct.  You can make 5 ghz every bit as directional as 2.4.  It's all in the antenna.

Comment: Agreed, this is simply wrong. It may be true that 2.4 GHz radiation diffracts around slightly larger obstacles than 5 GHz radiation, but any such effects would be marginal at best. Also, "5G" doesn't mean 5 GHz. It means "5th generation." The increased density of cell towers has nothing to do with the difference between 2.4 and 5 GHz, because cell phones don't use either of those frequencies for communicating with the tower. Rather, it's likely due to the fact that cellular device density has gotten larger than previous towers could handle.